# Netty 3.9: How to Reuse a Client Channel after disconnecting from server

Tags: netty

I am using Netty 3.9

I have a client scenario where i have to the operations in this order

1. connect
2. send 1 msg
3. recv 1 msg
4. disconnect

since connecting and disconnecting is a costly operation, i want to reuse Netty level objects as much as possible.

So i do the following

```
ClientBootStrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(new NioClientSocketChannelFactory);

bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new MyPipeLineFactory());
// set options : soLinger, keepAlive, tcpNoDelay, 
ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect(remoteAddr,localAddr);
f.awaitUninterruptibly();
Channel ch = f.getChannel();

// use the Channel, send/recv message

// disconnect the channel
ch.disconnect().awaitUninterruptibly();
// save the 'ch' in a map

// Now reuse the same Channel Object
// retreive 'ch'
ch.connect(remoteAddr)
```

the above line results in `java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException`, perhaps because the socket is closed. but there is no api in Netty which i can use to disconnect from the server and still keep the socket with me to reuse it for same remote addr by connecting again.

is it possible to reuse Netty Channel in this way? if yes how? do i need to set any option in the bootsrtap?

Answer (score 0):

Once disconnected in Netty 3, the channel is closed and cannot be reopened. You have to create a new one.

Another option would be to maintain your connection open (don't forget to have a mechanism of keepalive) while virtually closed from your protocol point of view, therefore implementing a sort of connection pool.

Comment: my requirement is to implement short connections, i.e. channel is supposed to be closed after one request-response. so a connection pool of alive connections doesnt suit my requirement.

Comment: i am not calling `ch.close()` , i am calling 'ch.disconnect` so should be able to `ch.connect`

Comment: So you have no choice. You have to recreate it, while IMHO reconnection is mostly what is going to take all latency, whatever you reconnect or create a new channel...

Comment: As I wrote : Disconnect in Netty 3 leads to a following close, so no difference there...